# Finding buffered frames in tf2_ros::Buffer (c++)

Tags: c++, ros-melodic, rosbag, tf2-ros, tf2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am creating a post-processing utility where I read all the transforms from a .bag file into a tf2_ros::Buffer.

I would like to be able to ask the Buffer for all the frames it has cached.   I don't see any **public** member functions in the [doccumentation](http://docs.ros.org/indigo/api/tf2_ros/html/c++/classtf2__ros_1_1Buffer.html#ab96886f1292cc3cd7452d65312ec94d0) that allow you to view cached frames.

What is the best way to access cached all the frames in a tf2_ros::Buffer?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/324348/finding-buffered-frames-in-tf2_ros::buffer-(c++)/) by [kkrasnosky](https://answers.ros.org/users/6226/kkrasnosky/) on ROS Answers with karma: 78 on 2019-05-30

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-05-30**:
I don't believe there is any support for that, but let's see if someone proves me wrong.

---

Edit: appears there are `BufferCore::allFramesAsYAML()` and [`BufferCore::_getFrameStrings(..)`](http://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/tf2/html/classtf2_1_1BufferCore.html#aba50090bdc09979c9b4f8323ab892e39). Would those suffice for what you are doing?

**Comment by [kkrasnosky](https://answers.ros.org/users/6226/kkrasnosky/) on 2019-05-30**:
`BufferCore::allFramesAsYAML()` will probably do the trick.   I will report my findings after I do some more testing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There are two methods for introspecting the state of the bufffer.

[allFramesAsString()](http://docs.ros.org/indigo/api/tf2/html/classtf2_1_1BufferCore.html#a6b0d5d9063101c3205b8d05202eef635) and [allFramesAsYaml(double)](http://docs.ros.org/indigo/api/tf2/html/classtf2_1_1BufferCore.html#a1b7ffec819a06ad226e30261b8f98759)

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2019-05-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [TGO](https://answers.ros.org/users/111689/tgo/) on 2022-08-03**:
How do you use them practically? Im trying all sorts of things to cout<< but not working!